# Application to create and manage a document structure in graphical way

Tags: php, javascript, web-applications, projects-and-solutions

Ok, the "title" isn't very clear but it's complicated to explain even in my native language (this is a prelude do "sorry for the various error that english speaking people will catch).

I'm working on a project to improve some web tools that my office still use.
One of that is a very very bad an basic CMS that needs to be revamped. Or completely burn.
So, i'm going to offer a new cms that can really make the job easier for all who have to publish something on the web-site.

To hit the point i'm looking for a web application that can realize and manage something like this:

```
Index
||
||__Cap. 1
|| |
|| |__Par. 1.1
|| | |
|| | |______Sect. 1.1.1
|| | |______Sect. 1.1.2
|| | |______Sect. 1.1.3
|| |__Par. 1.2
||
||__Cap. 2
|| |
|| |__Par. 2.1
|| |__Par. 2.2
```

And obviously manage the possibility to move an element and his son to another parent. etc. etc. but into a graphical UI not just an "add son", "add parent" button.
This product will go to people that probably barely knows the basic of M$ Words so i need something very very intuitive.

I'm not looking for a "ready-to-go" application of course, i know this is a particular request but if someone knows about a project that at least arrange document in an hierarchical structure that would be a very good point to start.
I'm very strong in php and js/jquery code so if you find something in that languages that would be great, anyway any languages will be ok (basic knowledge of java, asp, etc), i just need some more time maybe.

The final goal would be the creation of an automatism that link the document toghether (so you can navigate from sect. 1.1.1 to 1.1.2 and vice versa) without have to manually write the html code for each web page, assign to every element a pre-assigned models, and other nice things to make everything very easy to manage even with large web document (the medium document production is around 600-800 paper pages).

I was thinking about some cms but seems that every one use the same "old" method to link document toghether (field form for link, basic html code, etc) that will be perfect for little document, like a tech rewiev for example, but not for huge document.

All this words can be very hard to understand due my sleep deprivation for this project :P
So if something is not clear do not show mercy and tell me, i'll gladly explain better as possible.

Thanks in advance to anyone.

Comment: I'm not sure, are you searching something like http://www.jstree.com/ ?

Comment: Very interesting Riccardo. I'll give it a try, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decide about two things:

- database model (how to save this structure)
- frontend library/tool to edit the structure

For the database, I recommend using the tree traversal [described here with a lot of example SQL queries as a "nested set model"](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). It easily allows you to print the whole trees or subtrees and finding out the sibling nodes. The drawback is that more complex logistics is needed when modifying the tree.

For the javascript side, there is a lot of [jQuery plugins available](http://www.google.cz/search?q=jstree&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari&redir_esc=&ei=pfXDTcyZDZHKswab5KmZDw#hl=en&pq=jstree&xhr=t&q=tree%20jquery&cp=7&pf=p&sclient=psy&client=safari&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=tree%20jq&pbx=1&fp=a8d357d588b42a1a). I am sure you will find some that suit your needs and if not, it's not very difficult to come up with your own solution.

Server technology choice is up to you, do it in the same language you will do the rest of the system. Just make sure your framework/library goes well with AJAX.

Comment: That's some very good point to start. Thanks for your suggestions! I just reserve some days to check your link :)